# Передача объекта класса в форму

Tags: c#, winforms

начал изучать С# Windows forms. Для тренировки потихоньку пишу что то типа пошаговой игры. Вопрос такой - как передать уже созданный объект класса в другую форму, и изменить одно из полей этого объекта уже в той форме в которую он был передан?

Comment: Добавьте свой проблемный код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто создайте свойство в форме

```
Class MyForm {
public MyObject SharedObject {get; set;}
}

.....

MyFrom myform = new MyForm();

myform.SharedObject = new MyObject();

myform.SharedObject.SomeMethod();
myform.SharedObject.SomeProperty = ....
```

Comment: Самый правильный способ инъекции зависимости - передача в конструктор.

Comment: Да, конечно, про100 ещё надо будет и объяснить solid походу. Думаю для начала сойдёт и по проще решение

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для постоянных зависимостей - безусловно. А для временных, через конструктор такое себе решение. Создание формы - дорогая операция, так что формы, которые используются в приложении постоянно, но с разными данными удобнее один раз создать, руками или в каком-нибудь IoC-контейнере, и скармливать им новые данные через свойства или методы, а не создавать каждый раз внедряя зависимости через конструктор. А еще не плохо бы ненужные формы диспозить, освобождая системные хэндлы, об этом тоже все забывают, когда пишут очередной `new SomeForm.Show()`